# RMAN ORA-19913: unable to decrypt backup

Tags: encryption, rman

I have been sent a RMAN backup, which is dual encrypted, wallet and password.

The Oracle version is 11.1.0.7.

I am trying to restore the database on a new server.

I performed the following steps:

1. Create database with ORACLE_SID THEDB using a minimal init.ora file.
2. Configure the Wallet by copying the ewallet.p12 and cwallet.sso files to a directory, and then adding the ENCRYPTION_WALLET_LOCATION entry into sqlnet.ora.

The next steps are:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

startup nomount
select status from v$encryption_wallet;

STATUS
----------------
OPEN

quit
```

Then RMAN:

```
rman target / nocatalog
set decryption identified by 'the_backup_pwd';
restore controlfile from 'THEDB_CF_xxxxx_yyy';

ORA-19913: unable to decrypt backup
```

Now, the backup was taken using AES256 encryption, but the default encryption for this empty database is AES128.

I cannot issue the `CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES256'` command in RMAN as it fails with "database not mounted".

I am certain the wallet and password are correct, but still this error occurs.

What step is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out that this only happened if the RMAN Encyrption password had special characters like '$' etc.

The only workaround was to use a heredoc with the password hardcoded .. not great ...

```
rman / target << EOF
set decryption 'ThePa$$Word'

run {
..
}
EOF
```

Even when run interactively and the password was manually key it we still got the `ORA-19913: unable to decrypt backup`. It is obviously a Oracle RMAN bug.

Comment: I was running into the same error but I was making a stupid mistake: I had SET ENCRYPTION IDENTIFIED BY 'password' instead of SET DECRYPTION